# Jena - Access elements in model from a QuerySolution and update them

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I want to perform simple operations using one test model I created using Protégé 5. In my case I have a user defined this way in my owl file:

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&user-test-2;u01">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&user-test-2;user"/>
    <user-test-2:email rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">email1@test.net</user-test-2:email>
    <user-test-2:hasGender rdf:resource="&user-test-2;male"/>
    <user-test-2:isYearsOld rdf:resource="&user-test-2;18-24"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

I have been able to load the model correctly and perform a basic search using SPARQL to get male users and related properties, obtaining the following results:

```
        String fileName = "user-test-2.owl";
        Model model = RDFDataMgr.loadModel(fileName);
        final String ns = "http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/user-test-2#";


        String queryString =  "PREFIX test: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/user-test-2#> "
            + "SELECT ?subject "
            + "WHERE { ?subject test:hasGender test:male } ";
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
        ResultSet results =  qe.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);

        ------------
        | subject  |
        ============
        | test:u01 |
        -----------
```

Now I would like to access the properties of the owl:NamedIndividual and update one of them. For instance, to change the user's email.

**EDIT**

I have been able to access the properties using this code:

```
        Property emailDp = model.getProperty(ns + "email"); 
        Property isYearsOld = model.getProperty(ns + "isYearsOld"); 

        for ( ; results.hasNext() ; ) {
          QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution() ;
          Resource res = soln.getResource("subject");
          Resource user = model.getResource( res.getURI());  

          System.out.println(user.getProperty(emailDp));
          System.out.println(user.getProperty(isYearsOld));
    }
```

Now I would need to update one of them.

For the moment I have not found any useful example to perform these kind of things so any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at SPARQL Update.

Comment: In addition to @AndyS: [APACHE JENA ARQ - SPARQL Update](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/update.html)

Comment: any complete and operating example anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to update the property `emailDp` or `isYearsOld` of a given user.

Assuming a user only has one e-mail address and/or one age, we can get the property directly by calling:

```
Statement emailStatement = user.getProperty(emailDp);
Statement ageStatement = user.getProperty(isYearsOld);
```

The age or email of a user can then be retrieven using:

```
Resource email = (Resource) emailStatement.getObject();
Resource age = (Resource) ageStatement.getObject();
```

Updating either one of these can easily be done by:

```
user.removeProperty(emailDp, email);
user.removeProperty(isYearsOld, age);

user.addProperty(emailDp, newEmail);
user.addProperty(isYearsOld, newAge);
```

If a user has MORE THAN ONE of either, you will have to device if the new e-mail address replaces all old ones with `user.removeAll(emailDp)` or iterating over the list as you are doing and performing any kind of check, and delete the one you want, similar to above examples.